# Using sql recordset to determine which userform is shown on loading

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

I have a VBA application in word. When the user opens the document they will see one of two version of the main menu depending on their access level which is stored in a SQL table. The access level column is an integer and is either "1" or "0". I am trying to use a simple if then statement in VBA based on the results of querying that table, but I keep getting a type mismatch on my rs object.

```
Sub accesscheck()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
Database_Name = "PIA"
SQLStr = "select [AccessLevel] from dbo.[AttendanceUsers] Where [Adusername] ='" & getWinUser & "'"
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & vbNullString
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
If rs = "1" Then MainMenu.Show vbModeless Else OLMenu.Show
rs.Close
Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the column name and also no need of `""`. Try this :

```
....
....
If rs("AccessLevel") = 1 Then MainMenu.Show vbModeless Else OLMenu.Show
....
....
```